# How to delete object instance already rendered on screen

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am using forEach to create multiple cards that can be dragged. Say I drag it to the left, similar to tinder card functionality I want it to delete this instance of the card. I understand how to remove from a list for example but how would I not only delete this instance of the card but re-render the screen to reflect it being gone.

```
import Photos
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Actual Card
            ZStack{
                ForEach(imageObjectGroup){ card in
                    CardView(card: card).padding(8)
                }
            }.zIndex(1.0)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

//Card Structure
struct CardView: View{
    @State var card: ImageObject
    let cardGradient = Gradient(colors: [Color.blue.opacity(25), Color.black.opacity(0.5)])
    var body: some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
            LinearGradient(gradient: cardGradient, startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
        //ZStack follows the coordinates of the card model
        }.offset(x: card.x, y: card.y).rotationEffect(.init(degrees: card.degree)).gesture(
            //Gesture recognizer updates coordinate values
            DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                card.x = value.translation.width
                card.y = value.translation.height
                card.degree = 7 * (value.translation.width > 0 ? 1 : -1)
            }
            //When user stops dragging
            .onEnded { value in
                withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 50, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0)){
                        switch value.translation.width {
                            case 0...100:
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0
                            // Keep
                            case let x where x > 100:
                                card.x = 200; card.degree = 12
                            case (-100)...(-1):
                                card.x = 0; card.degree = 0; card.y = 0;
                            // Delete
                            case let x where x < -100:
                                card.x = -200; card.degree = -12
                                // DELETE CARD CODE HERE
                            default: card.x = 0; card.y = 0
                        }
                }
            }
        ).cornerRadius(8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about deleting the view or the information that makes up the card? SwiftUI handles the view. You don't have to delete it explicitly, in fact you can't. The system handles all of that. As to deleting the card data itself, you could have a delete func in the Card model that you could call to delete the card you just discarded.

Comment: to "delete" the Card, you just delete the entry in your "imageObjectGroup", and the view will do the rest.

Comment: @workingdog I tried deleting the entry in imageObjectGroup but this doesn't delete the card in view. Which makes sense because forEach rendered all the cards already so any changes aren't tracked

Comment: I don't know what is in imageObjectGroup, but if you make it (somehow) an ObservableObject then any change to it, will re-render the view and "delete" the card.

Comment: @workingdog essentially it's a group of image objects. Each image object instance is being rendered as a separate card. I'll look into ObservableObject it seems promising

Comment: I notice for example with the on drag it's changing the card.x attribute so I'm assuming I have to delete this card instance in some way rather than the object it's associated with

Comment: yes, look into ObservableObject, it is promising, you will see that deleting the image will remove the card from the view. Good luck.